# Erlang OTP release 18 does not work with erlydtl

Tags: regex, django-templates, erlang

After updating Erlang OTP from 17.5 to 18.
When run make it displays the following errors:

> ERROR: **OTP release 18** does not match required regex
>   R15B0[^1]|R16B$|R16B[^0]|R16B0[^3]|R16B03-1|17 ERROR: compile failed
>   while processing /home/dev/bongthom/deps/eunit_formatters: rebar_abort

But, it works, if I remove the erlydtl dependencies from relx.conf and *.app.src

Any recommend on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constraint is set [here](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/blob/master/rebar.config#L5). So maybe you would want just to delete this line (or better if you are using rebar, just use [overrides mechanism](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration#overrides) if you do not want to modify erlydtl.app.src).

Also I'd recommend you to run erlydtl tests to ensure stuff really works (but not just compiles).